# Classify the wind direction in several classes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Here is my question.
I have one dataframe **df** which contain two columns named *date* and *wd*.
And the *wd* means the wind direction which range from (0~360).
So, the **df**  represent the wind direction of somewhere in certain time frame.

**I want to classify those wind direction into 16 classes like this:**
http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-8/30080798.jpg

The ranges are presented here.

http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-8/8398960.jpg

This is what I can deal with now:

```
wd_stat = []
for i in range(0,len(df),1):
    wd = df.wd.iloc[i]
    ### NNE 11.25-33.75
    if 11.25 <= wd < 33.75:
       wd_stat.append("NNE")    
    ### NE 33.75-56.25   
    if (33.75 <=wd < 56.25):
       wd_stat.append("NE")
    ### ENE 56.25 - 78.75    
    if (56.25 <=wd < 78.75):
       wd_stat.append("ENE") 
    if (78.75 <=wd < 101.25):
       wd_stat.append("E") 
    if (101.25 <=wd < 123.75):
        wd_stat.append("ESE") 
      .....not done yet......
```

My method was inflexible and dump.
Can anyone give some advices to deal the classify problem like this(number range into certain characters) in high efficience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice way to do these kind of things is by using [numpy.digitize()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). It takes an array of bins and values and returns the index into which bin each value falls. Use these indices in a matching string array to get what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"wd": pd.Series([20.1,50,8.4,359,243,123])})

directions = np.array('N NNE NE ENE E ESE SE SSE S SSW SW WSW W WNW NW NNW N'.split())
bins = np.arange(11.25, 372, 22.5)
df['wd_stat'] = directions[np.digitize(df['wd'], bins)]
print df

      wd wd_stat
0   20.1     NNE
1   50.0      NE
2    8.4       N
3  359.0       N
4  243.0     WSW
5  123.0     ESE
```

Comment: it's indeed very elegant solution!

Comment: Another question follows here. In your method, the [0~11.25] range is replaced by [360~371.25]. So I was wondering add 360 to those columns  before digitize it. Using `df.iloc[df.loc[ 0<= df['wd'] < 11.25].index]["wd"]+360` can't achieve that. How to add  constant to specific rows based on certain classess?

Comment: If you look closely, you see that i have defined the 'N' direction twice in the directions array. This corresponds to the two bins [-np.inf, 11.25] and [348.75, 371.25]. Come to think of it, the top limit is even unnecessary, and you might as well define bins = np.arange(11.25, 360, 22.5). Bottom line is: there is no need to alter the values before digitizing.

Comment: Thanks! When I directly use `np.ditigize`, it can't work because there are some NAN value in  practical data. So I set another direction 'NAN'. After ditigize, I use `df = df.replace("NAN", np.nan)` solving it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"wd": pd.Series([20.1,50,8.4 ])})
print df
     wd
0  20.1
1  50.0
2   8.4

print (df.wd >= 11.25 ) & (df.wd < 33.75 )
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: wd, dtype: bool

df.loc[(df.wd >= 11.25 ) & (df.wd < 33.75 ), 'new'] = 'NNE'
df.loc[(df.wd >= 33.75 ) & (df.wd < 56.25 ), 'new'] = 'NE'
print df
     wd  new
0  20.1  NNE
1  50.0   NE
2   8.4  NaN
```