# Naming intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem turning these intervals into a new column with the categories I want.

I have tried many different variations of the greater than. I did get it to work, by getting the middle bracket to become NaN and then rename them afterwards. The code works fine for line 1 & 3, it is just when I want to create the middle interval that it does not work. I would be forever grateful for any help.

```
df["AgeGroup"] = df.loc[df["Age"] < 25, "AgeGroup"] = "kid"
df["AgeGroup"] = df.loc[df["Age"] >= 25 & df.loc["Age"] < 50, "AgeGroup"] = "young"
df["AgeGroup"] = df.loc[df["Age"] >= 50, "AgeGroup"] = "old"
```

Also tried and similar variations.  inbetween.

```
df["AgeGroup"] = df.loc[df["Age"] < 25, "AgeGroup"] = "kid"
df["AgeGroup"] = df.loc[df["Age"] >= 25 < 50, "AgeGroup"] = "young"
df["AgeGroup"] = df.loc[df["Age"] >= 50, "AgeGroup"] = "old"
```

Varies between syntax errors and The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You have to use parenthesis `( df.Age >= 25 ) & (df.Age < 50)` or use `gt`, `le` etc.. like `df.Age.ge(25) & df.Age.lt(50)`

Answer (score 3):

You might use `pd.cut` as in the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age": [25, 40, 51, 4, 90]})
bins = [0, 24, 49, 200]
labels = ["kid", "young", "old"]
df["AgeGroup"] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
cond=[df["Age"] < 25,(df["Age"] >= 25) & (df["Age"] < 50),df["Age"] >= 50]
val=['kid','young','old']
df["AgeGroup"]=np.select(cond,val)
```

Also you can use:

```
df.loc[df["Age"] < 25, "AgeGroup"] = "kid"
df.loc[(df["Age"] >= 25 )&(df["Age"] < 50), "AgeGroup"] = "young"
df.loc[df["Age"] >= 50, "AgeGroup"] = "old"
```

**it is important to use parentheses:**

```
(df["Age"] >= 25 )&(df["Age"] < 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to define a function and then use `df.map()`

```
def age_group(age):
    if age < 25: ageGroup = "kid"
    elif (age >= 25) and (age < 50): ageGroup = "young"
    else: ageGroup = "old"
    return ageGroup

df['AgeGroup'] = df['Age'].map(age_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a very similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865550/2354344). The best way to do this is using `numpy.digitize()`.

```
classes = np.array(['kid', 'young', 'old'])
df['AgeGroup'] = classes[np.digitize(df['Age'], [25, 50])]
```

I just saw the answer using `pd.cut()`, this is basically the numpy equivalent.